# SQL: Show search parameter in result, even if result is null

Tags: mysql, null

I have a table:

**MyTable**

```
ID | Name
1 | ok
2 | ok
3 | ok
4 | ok
```

I would like to write query which will return parameters used in "IN" clause, even if result is null (such row doesn't exist in table).

Something like:

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  Name

FROM MyTable
WHERE ID in ('ABC', 'DEF', 1)
```

**Desired result:**
(addition: X column is not defined in MyTable)

```
X | ID | Name
ABC | Null | Null
DEF | Null | Null
1 | 1 | ok
```

Is it possible?

I've tried something like:

```
SELECT 
 IFNULL(t2.ID,"?")

FROM MyTable t1
LEFT JOIN MyTable t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
 AND t2.ID IN ('ABC')
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you need it for?

Comment: I need to check ID's from one database which does not exist in another database (in MyTable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that from values in an `IN` list; it's not possible to return those values in the resultset. That's not possible.

The rows in the resultset have to be returned from some rowsource in the FROM clause. Normally, that's a table, but we can also use an inline view as a rowsource.

To return the three rows you are looking for, consider this query:

```
   SELECT 'ABC' AS `X`
    UNION ALL
   SELECT 'DEF'
    UNION ALL
   SELECT 1
```

If we wrap that in parens, and assign it an alias, we can reference that like a table. For example:

```
SELECT v.X
  FROM (
         SELECT 'ABC' AS `X`
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'DEF'
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 1
       ) v
```

Notice that the query inside the parens replaces what would normally be a table. That query assigns an alias `v`; we've essentially created a table named `v`.

Once you're over that hump, it's easy. Add an outer join to the table you want to check from matching values

```
SELECT v.X
     , t.ID
     , t.Name
  FROM (
         SELECT 'ABC' AS `X`
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'DEF'
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 1
       ) v
  LEFT
  JOIN MyTable t
    ON t.ID = v.X
 ORDER BY v.X
```

---

NOTE: the mix of datatypes (string literals and a numeric literal) is a bit odd... column `X` is going to have a single datatype returned, you're going to want that to match the datatype of the `ID` column.  (I suspect that `'ABC'` and `'DEF'` were just some placeholders given in your example.) The point is, beware of implicit datatype conversions. If you need datatype conversions to happen, it's usually safest to make those explicit using appropriate expressions, e.g. `CAST(x`, `CONVERT(x`, `STR_TO_DATE(x`, `x+0`, etc.

Comment: Hey, sure, 'ABC' was used only in this example (to show that I want to retrieve record which for sure is not available in the column) and it is not stored in db. Thank you for your help and detailed explanation! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a strange desired result-set , here is a way to do it

```
select 
x.ID,
t.name from ( 
  select 'abc' as ID 
  union all 
  select 'def' 
  union all 
  select '1'
)x left join my_table t on t.ID = x.ID ;
```